# QWebView: document.location.replace have the wrong behavior inside an iframe

Tags: qt, google-chrome, qwebview

This is hard to explain, but I will try

I have a local apache in my machine. Inside apache I have 2 folders, *foldera* and *folderb*. In *foldera/a.html* I have a page with iframe pointing to *folderb/b.html*. Inside *b.html* there is a link with its href executing the following code:

```
function go() {
    document.location.replace('c.html');
}
```

If I use **Chrome** and then go to *http://mymachine.com/foldera/a.html* click in the link the iframe goes to *folderb/c.html* which is the expected behavior.

**The strange thing is**:

I have a QtApp with a QWebView. It goes to the *foldera/a.html* file and execute the following javascript code:

```
var a = document.querySelector('#ifrm').contentWindow.document.querySelector('a')
myLib.doClick(a)
```

doClick is a function that "click" in an object.

**the strange this is that my iframe tries to go to *foldera/c.html*** The *replace* function thinks it is in the wrong location, the location of the parent window and replaces the last bit of the url (b.html -> c.html)

The code of the click function is working well in any other case

```
 click: function (target ) {
    relatedTarget = relatedTarget || null;
    var customEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    customEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, detail,
                 0, 0, 0, 0,
                 false, false, false, false,
                 0, null);
     target.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}
```

I tried changing *window* and *document* to the iframe.contentWindow and iframe.contentWindow.document and I get the same behavior

Is this the expected behavior? Some knows if it is a real bug? Can i do somethin else?

Thanks for every answer